2019 MacBook Pro Intermittently Rejects Login Password, Requires Apple ID Reset
I'm experiencing a persistent issue with my 2019 MacBook Pro running the latest macOS.
Every 1-3 months, my system fails to recognize my login password. To regain access, I have to use my Apple ID to log in and "reset" the password to the exact same one I was already using.
Steps I've already taken to troubleshoot:

Verified keyboard functionality (including testing with an external
keyboard)
Ensured macOS is up to date
Performed NVRAM/PRAM reset
Performed SMC reset

I have also changed passwords to something with just letters (no symbols etc) and it still happens.
Despite all these efforts, the problem continues to occur sporadically.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
